# How do I insert only unique elements in array using Prisma for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, prisma

I have written a query to insert an ID into an array field. It's possible that users try to click twice, or anyhow that the same ID can be inserted twice, which is what I want to avoid. It was possible to achieve this using native MongoDB, but I am not able to find how to do this using Prisma. Below is my code. Any help will be appreciated!

```
await this.prisma.finderEntity.upsert({
                where: { userId },
                create: {
                    ...body,
                    isActive: true,
                    isDeleted: false,
                    missingItemIds: [missingItemExists.id],
                },
                update: {
                    missingItemIds: {
                        push: missingItemExists.id,
                    },
                },
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

in your prisma schema you just have to have to add an
@@unique annotation on the wanted property or properties.

Your question is not really accurate but I believe you will find better explanations then I can give you here :

[Prisma article about working with id/unique constraint](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/special-fields-and-types/working-with-composite-ids-and-constraints)

Comment: I did not use the @unique annotation on the array field, also unsure if it can be used like that. I will add it, test it, and let you know. Thank you